# group zipcode by duplicates and count

Tags: javascript

I want to group the zipcode by duplicate values. I have an array of zipcodes that contains duplicates.

```
var ArrayOfZipCodes = [{"zipCode" : "12345"},{"zipCode" : "24567"}, {"zipCode" : "24567"}, 
       {"zipCode" : "24567"} , {"zipCode" : "02895"} , {"zipCode" : "02861"} , {"zipCode" : "02895"}]
```

**Output Needed:**

```
sorting the zipCodes and then grouping it.

var finalOutput = [{"zipCode" : "12345", from: "1"},{"zipCode" : "24567", from: "2 - 4"},
           {"zipCode" : "02861", from: "5"}, {"zipCode" : "02895", from: "6-7"} ]
```

Here is my implementation:

```
ArrayOfZipCodes.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a['zipCode'] - b['zipCode'];
});

ArrayOfZipCodes.forEach((item, index) => (item['id'] = index + 1));

const lookup = zipCodes.reduce((a, e) => {
    a[e['zipCode']] = ++a[e['zipCode']] || 0;
    return a;
}, {});

let group = ArrayOfZipCodes.filter(e => lookup[e['zipCode']]);

const filteredArr = group.reduce((acc, current, currentIndex, array) => {
    const x = acc.find(item => item['zipCode'] === current['zipCode']);
    if (x) {
        acc[0]['from'] = x['id'] + "-" + (array.length + 1);
    }
    return acc.concat([current]);

}, []);

var uniq = {}

var arrFiltered = ArrayOfZipCodes.filter(obj => !uniq[obj['zipCode']] && (uniq[obj['zipCode']] = true));

let finalArr = arrFiltered.concat(filteredArr);
console.log("finalArr", finalArr)
```

When I run, I get, `[circular object Object]` and not the mentioned above output.

Comment: Is the value of `from` important in your output? Do you need to know the number of instances of each zip code? The positions in the original array so you can access them later? Or is that string you are showing the format you actually need?

Comment: from is important as i use that to point in the map... clustering the similar zipcodes

Comment: Why `02895` from is `6-7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do what you're looking for.

```js
const arrayOfZipCodes = [
  {zipCode: "12345"},
  {zipCode: "24567"},
  {zipCode: "24567"},
  {zipCode: "24567"},
  {zipCode: "02895"},
  {zipCode: "02861"},
  {zipCode: "02895"},
];

const sortedZipCodes = arrayOfZipCodes.map(z => z.zipCode).sort();

const output = [...new Set(sortedZipCodes)].map(zipCode => {
  const first = sortedZipCodes.indexOf(zipCode);
  const last = sortedZipCodes.lastIndexOf(zipCode);
  const from = first === last ? `${first}` : `${first} - ${last}`;
  return {zipCode, from};
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks, can the count start from 1 instead of zero

Comment: Sure. "const from = first === last ? `${first + 1}` : `${first + 1} - ${last + 1}`;"

Comment: [...new Set(sortedZipCodes)], this line is throwing me error... is there a way we can use alternative way

Comment: What is the value of `sortedZipCodes`? It should be a sorted ARRAY of strings (zipcodes).

Comment: Array of objects in original format with pointer property attached as an addition, ...new Set is throwing error in code... guess its removing duplicates...

Comment: You need to either provide the error in full or answer the question that I asked. If `sortedZipCodes` is not an array of strings, you have not followed the code I have provided to generate that array.

Comment: I get this error, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5391

Comment: The page you linked has the answer to how to fix the error.

Comment: Yes, but i cannot change the tsconfig.json for this one.

Comment: Then use a polyfill: E.g. https://github.com/jfriend00/ES6-Set or https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-set

Comment: Thanks Chase, do you see this cannot be solved without using set?

Comment: Any method of getting a unique set of values works fine. Even lodash `_.uniq` or similar.